# mental ability whiz

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I got a difficult question in a national olympiad, and was not able to solve it. I can't wait for answer keys. please solve it for me!

If $3a = 4b = 6c$ and $a + b + c = 27 \sqrt{29}$, then what is the value of $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ ?

A- $3\sqrt{29}$

B- $81$

C- $87$

D- $9/2 \sqrt{29}$

Comment: Why can't you wait for answer keys -- is the contest still ongoing??

Comment: yes sir, the competition is still going on. Actually, the first level of the competition took place today (28-11-2013). The keys will be out after 2 weeks of examination but i wanted to confirm all my answers now. Thanks a lot for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 4):

Let the common value of $3a$, $4b$ and $6c$ be $12x$. Then your equation for $a+b+c$ gives you $x$, and hence each of $a$, $b$, $c$. Now plug into the expression you're asked about.

Answer (score 0):

$b=\frac{3c}{2}, a=2c$
$$c(1+\frac{3}{2}+2)=27\sqrt{29}$$
find $a$ then $b$  and $c$. answer is  $87$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $3a = 4b = 6c = 12x$ thus $a = 4x$, $b = 3x$, $c = 2x$

$$
a + b + c = 4x + 3x + 2x = 9x = 27 \sqrt{29} \Rightarrow x = 3 \sqrt{29}
$$

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} & = \sqrt{(4x)^2 + (3x)^2 + (2x)^2} \\
          & = \sqrt{16x^2 + 9x^2 + 4x^2} \\
          & = \sqrt{29} \cdot x \\
          & = \sqrt{29} \cdot 3 \sqrt{29} \\
          & = 3 \times 29 \\
          & = 87
\end{align}$$

Using the hint from another answer here.

Answer (score -1):

Solution ratios of $a:b:c = 4:3:2 $

$a=12,\; b=9, \;c=6,\; \text{(approximate)}$

So $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}= 3\sqrt{29}$

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$.${}{}$

Comment: Please try to format your answer, at the very least, so it is presentable and understandable.